# Refresh control and Search bar causes weird offset on table view / scroll view, how to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uirefreshcontrol

I'm having this issue that sometimes the refresh control and the table view gets shifted down if I do some search while refreshing.

The problem is better explained in the images below. It is like the whole view shifts.

[image]

1 - Table and refresh control are in its normal state.
2 - Table, search bar, and refresh control has shifted.
3 - If pull to refresh, I can see that refresh control has shifted too.

I've changed background colors and I could see that the whole tableview shifts.

It is a UIViewController with a TableView Inside.

```
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
//searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try unchecking `adjustScrollViewInsets` of `UIViewController` in your IB.

Comment: It's already unchecked. And Content insets behavior of table view is set to never.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear , i give you suggestions according to my understanding.

If you don't like the space between nav and search bar, just disable the bounce of tableview.

[image]

If you think the space is too large, you may set the wrong constraint constant between tableview and top view. Here if I set -50, it could be very far.

Finally you may add a beautiful picture as a background of the view, the space can be filled with interesting effect. Hope this can help you.

[image]

Comment: Can't disable the bounce because it will disable the "pull to refresh" feature